# Rspec passing GET params to a PUT action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec

I'm trying to test a PUT request to a controller, but I need to send GET and POST body params to the action. The params cannot be mashed together, as certain parts of the code access the GET params explicitly.

How do you pass GET params to a put action?

I have this test :

```
it "updates the account password to the provided value" do
  put(:update, @params)
  @account.reload.crypted_password.should == PasswordAccount.encrypt(@newpass, @account.password_salt)
end
```

How can i add a "token" param to the query string sent to the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE :

After investigating the rails testing source code I came up with the following :

```
def process_with_query(action, query_string="", parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil, http_method = 'GET')
  # Sanity check for required instance variables so we can give an
  # understandable error message.
  %w(@routes @controller @request @response).each do |iv_name|
    if !(instance_variable_names.include?(iv_name) || instance_variable_names.include?(iv_name.to_sym)) || instance_variable_get(iv_name).nil?
      raise "#{iv_name} is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method."
    end
  end

  @request.recycle!
  @response.recycle!
  @controller.response_body = nil
  @controller.formats = nil
  @controller.params = nil

  @html_document = nil
  @request.env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = http_method

  parameters ||= {}
  @request.assign_parameters(@routes, @controller.class.name.underscore.sub(/_controller$/, ''), action.to_s, parameters)

  @request.session = ActionController::TestSession.new(session) unless session.nil?
  @request.session["flash"] = @request.flash.update(flash || {})
  @request.session["flash"].sweep

  @controller.request = @request
  @controller.params.merge!(parameters)
  build_request_uri(action, parameters)
  @request.env["QUERY_STRING"] = query_string.kind_of?(Hash) ? query_string.to_param : query_string
  @request.env["action_dispatch.request.query_parameters"] = Rack::Utils.parse_query(@request.env["QUERY_STRING"])
  ActionController::Base.class_eval { include ActionController::Testing }
  @controller.process_with_new_base_test(@request, @response)
  @request.session.delete('flash') if @request.session['flash'].blank?
  @response
end

def put_with_query(action, query_string="", parameters=nil, session=nil, flash=nil)
  process_with_query(action, query_string, parameters, session, flash, 'PUT')
end

def post_with_query(action, query_string="", parameters=nil, session=nil, flash=nil)
  process_with_query(action, query_string, parameters, session, flash, 'POST')
end
```

Any comments?

Answer (score 3):

The `put` method is defined in Rails' `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-put

From what I can see there is no support for separating the different get/post params, but why not just include it in the `@params` variable?

```
put(:update, @params.merge(:token => 'gobbledygook'))
```

By the time your code sees the params, Rails has already merged the get/post params for you anyhow.

HTH,
David

Comment: I want to keep them separate on the controller side. I'm directly accessing request.GET and request.POST in some rack middleware.